# Display a heading from a table with a list item beneath it

Tags: php, html, mysql

What I am trying to achieve is get the data from my database outputted in this format. I know how to get both of them seperately but I can't figure out how to get it displayed like this.

```
<h3>Category1</h3>
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>

<h3>Category2</h3>
<li>Item1</li>
<li>Item2</li>
```

So far i've made 2 database one with the categories and another one with a foreign key to the categories that includes the list items. I think this is the only way?

So far i'm just using a foreach to display the data but a second foreach containing the relevant list items needs to be run. Can anyone help a noob out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Have a table this way:

```
+-------+-----------+
| Item  | Category  |
+-------+-----------+
| Item1 | Category1 |
| Item2 | Category1 |
| Item1 | Category2 |
| Item2 | Category2 |
+-------+-----------+
```

#### Code:

Now, when you are fetching data, use this way:

```
<?php
  $current_cat = "";
  foreach ($data = fetch_data_as_array($row))
  {
    if ($current_cat != $data["category"])
      echo '<h3>' . $categoryname . '</h3>';
    echo '<li>' . $data["item"] . '</li>';
    $current_cat = $data["category"];
  }
?>
```

Each time when you fetch a data, it checks for the old one. If both are not same, it echoes out the header.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for... but here's what I usually do:

```
$old_id_category = 0;
while($ln = $conn->fetch_array()){
  /* DATA FROM THE DATABASE */
  $id_category = $ln["id_category"];
  $categoryname = $ln["categoryname"];
  $itemname = $ln["itemname"];

  /* WHEN THE CATEGORY CHANGES */
  if($id_category != $old_id_category){
         /* PRINT HEADER */
         print("<h3>".$categoryname."</h3>");
         $old_id_category = $id_category;
  }
  /* PRINT LIST ITEMS */
  print("<li>".$itemname."</li>");
}
```

Hope it helps.

EDITED: Added the h3 and li tags.